# CLIPS интерпретатор: сохранение истории команд

Tags: linux, clips

```
$ clips
         CLIPS (V6.24 06/15/06)
CLIPS> asdf
asdf
CLIPS> ^[[A   <----- здесь была нажата стрелка вверх
```

Можно ли при нажатии стрелки вверх отображать предыдущие записи как в обычном терминале Linux?

Comment: должно работать из коробки... clisp собран с  `--with-readline`?

Comment: прошу прощения, очитался —  думал речь о cli**sp**

Comment: По-простому ни как не сделать... можно дописать поддержку readline'а самостоятельно, но из-за лицензии в апстрим это не примут.